# xpages: is it possible to export data to excel dynamically (depends on user's selection)?

Tags: excel, xpages

May I ask is it possible to export data to excel dynamically (depends on user's selection)?

Imagine the following scenario:

The user login to the program, it will display the user name (member), the group that user currently belongs to and the user is allow to choose the future group that wants to assign.

[image]

Suppose a user test 001 belongs to Group B and the user wants to assign to Group D, the user clicks the Submit button, the program will direct the user to the following page.

The page will display the result.

The table will show a list of activity that related to the future group(Group D), the user can see which activity is joined with the  joined date and which activity is not join.

[image]

The user is allowed to export the result to excel by click the export button.

The excel will probably look like this:

[image]

We use an agent to export the excel file.

Here is our code:

```
Sub Initialize
Print |Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel| 


Print "<tr><td>Result<br></td></tr>"
Print "<br>"
Print "<tr><td>Member</td><td>Test 001</td></tr>"
Print "<br>"
Print "<table border = 1><tr><th>Activity</th><th>Joined</th></tr>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity 1</td><td>Yes</td></tr>"
Print"<tr><td>Activity 2</td><td>No</td></tr>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity 3</td><td>No</td></tr>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity 4</td><td>Yes</td></tr>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity 5</td><td>No</td></tr>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity 6</td><td>No</td></tr></table>"
Print "<br>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity Joined</td><td>2</td></tr><br>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity Not Joined</td><td>4</td></tr><br>"


End Sub
```

However when we run the agent, the excel looks strange.

[image]

Due to our team is not good at develop xpages application, I should be grateful if you would give advice on these questions please.

1. Is it possible to implement the whole scenario in xpages?
2. We are sure that we will have lots of task like this scenario develop in xpages, so is there any way to export data to excel dynamically?
3. Our agent can export the excel file but the excel looks very strange, is something wrong in our code?

Sorry for my bad English and I appreciate any advice. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would like ask a question about the version of Domino Designer please. Assume we upgrade the Domino Designer to version 8.5.3, and we shall able to write java code or use Apache POI 4, is this concept correct? We develop a web application to the user. But the user does not have Domino Designer and only have IBM Lotus Notes 8.5.2 for send/receive emails, so can the user use the web application that designed with different versions? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following OpenNTF Project [POI 4 XPages](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/POI%204%20XPages/summary).

The key benefits:

- [**Apache POI**](https://poi.apache.org/) is a very good open source project.
  *I have it in use for many years without any troubles.*
- You can write your code in **Java**
- You can implement the whole scenario in **XPages** *(e.g. do it with an XAgent which can work on the selected documents)*

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I visited the website and I realised the POI 4 Pages seems available for Domino 9 or Domino 8.5.3. Sadly, our team is using 8.5.2, so we may think about upgrade the version or find another way to do the task. Anyway, I appreciate for your answer, thank you very much.